# Partial Specialization of Alias Templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, partial-specialization

Partial specializations of alias templates are not permitted:

For example, trying to be creative, yields this error in clang:

```
template <typename T>
using unwrapped_future_t = T;

template <typename T>
using unwrapped_future_t<future<T>> = typename future<T>::value_type;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
> error: partial specialization of alias templates is not permitted
```

Why is this not permitted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2002/n1406.pdf) of alias templates:

> **2.2 The Main Choice: Specialization vs. Everything Else**
>
> After discussion on the reflectors and in the Evolution WG, it turns out that we have to choose between two mutually exclusive models:
>
> 1. A typedef template is not itself an alias; only the (possibly-specialized) instantiations of the typedef template are aliases. This choice allows us to have specialization of typedef templates.
> 2. A typedef template is itself an alias; it cannot be specialized. This choice would allow:
>
>    - deduction on typedef template function parameters (see 2.4)
>    - a declaration expressed using typedef templates be the same as the declaration without
>        typedef templates (see 2.5)
>    - typedef templates to match template template parameters (see 2.6)

Comment: The very next sentence is "This paper proposes Option 1, thus favoring specialization..." Where is the answer for why that option was _not_ chosen?

Comment: @Lack I don't know that much, but I can guess: committee vote, majority for option 2.